What did Gill write in 1972 about P and NP?
Cited in Kozen's paper on subrecursive indexing (here) appears a paper by John Gill called "Axiomatic Independence of the question P=NP?". What is this paper about and how does it relate to the Baker, Gill and Solovay result? I couldn't find it anywhere.
In Google Scholar it appears as "Axiomatic Independence of the Question NP&equil; P?", which is also cited here and here.

It's hard to know.  It might have been an unpublished manuscript that Gill shared with Kozen, but was never published.  It does not seem to appear in any list of Stanford tech reports that I could find.
